# Formatting date in Java

Tags: java, date, datetime, timestamp

I am having a problem with formating a date using Java. The date formatter seems to parse my string using BST (British Summer Time) and not GMT+0 as defined by +0000 in the dateStr string in the code below.

```
String dateStr = "Tue Oct 02 01:06:00 +0000 2012";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");  
Date date = df.parse(dateStr);

// Test the date        
System.out.println(date.toString());
```

When I run the above code I get:

```
Tue Oct 02 02:06:00 BST 2012
```

Which is evidently not what I want. A useful point of information might be that when I run the following:

```
System.out.println(TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName());
```

I get:

```
Greenwich Mean Time
```

The output I'm trying to get is

```
Tue Oct 02 01:06:00 GMT 2012
```

I've already tried .setTimeZone on df but to no avail.

Comment: Did you mean to say GMT in your expected output? You said BST which seems to contradict your discussion.

Comment: Woops. Yes! Edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.toString()` method is using your locale when printing the date.

Use:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println(format.format(date));
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that Tue Oct 02 02:06:00 BST 2012 is the same time as Tue Oct 02 01:06:00 +0000 2012, just expressed in a different time zone.  `java.util.Date` doesn't really deal with time zones, so as far as its concerned, there is no difference.  The Date object you've constructed represents the correct date and time you want.

The `Date.toString()` method is essentially just a formatter that uses your JRE default TimeZone in its formatting.  If you want to test that the Date object is correct, then you should build a `java.util.Date` object (using `java.util.Calendar` - most of the Date constructors have been deprecated) to test against.  If you want to create a display string, then you should use the `SimpleDateFormatter` instance you've already created to format the Date object.

If you do need an object that stores TimeZone information, then you should use `java.util.Calendar`.  `java.util.Date` is almost deprecated to the point of being unusable anyway.  Or, do the same as I am and wait for the new Data and Time API coming out in Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that BST is already deprecated in SE 7.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like here:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy",
                Locale.CANADA);
```

add Local args to `SimpleDateFormat` constructor